# Conversion from argument 1 of "QWidget *" to "QGroupBox *" not possible

Tags: qt, qwidget, qgroupbox

this is my first question and I'm quite struggeling. I'm using Qt for creating a software for excentric viewing. A group of students did this project before, so I got pre-made code to work with.

My problem is the following one: 
I am not coding the usual way, I use the QDesigner. I have a Scroll Area where I want to fit some QGroupBoxes inside. There is a general box named "Properties" which holds some other boxes with a vertical layout.

Now one of the boxes is called "symbolgen" and is using a custom class, called "SymbolGen". The class is defined as followed:

```
class SymbolGen : public QGroupBox
```

Now what I like to do is to extract alle boxes from the "Properties" box. That means: I want to replace the Group "Properties" by a label "Properties" and underneath with the smaller boxes. Now what Qt says to me is the following:

```
Fehler: C2664: "SymbolGen::SymbolGen(const SymbolGen &)" : Konvertierung von Argument 1 von "QWidget *" in "QGroupBox *" nicht m”glich
```

Yes, I am German, in English:

```
Error: C2664: "SymbolGen::SymbolGen(const SymbolGen &)" : Conversion from argument 1 of "QWidget *" to "QGroupBox *" not possible.
```

What I see here is, that this specific Group Box "symbolgen" (holds some important variables in the class) **needs** another group box around. So how can I get this box separated without error?

Thanks for your help!

edit://Line that causes this error:

```
symbolgen = new SymbolGen(scrollAreaWidgetContents_2);
```

This one is found at "ui_admin.h".

edit://Definition of "scrollAreaWidgetContents_2" from "ui_admin.h":

```
scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 = new QWidget();
scrollAreaWidgetContents_2->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("scrollAreaWidgetContents_2"));
scrollAreaWidgetContents_2->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 503, 851));
```

edit://SymbolGen::SymbolGen(const SymbolGen &):

```
SymbolGen::SymbolGen(QGroupBox *g) : QGroupBox(g)
{
    srand (time(NULL));

    //Wörterquelle lesen

    std::ifstream f("source/ngerman.txt");
    std::string l;
    if(f.is_open())
    {
        while(f.good())
        {
            getline(f,l);
            words.push_back(l);
            //if( words.size() > 10000 ) break;
        }
    }
    f.close();

    //Satzquelle lesen
    std::ifstream fs("source/sentences.txt");
    //std::string l;
    if(fs.is_open())
    {
        while(fs.good())
        {
            getline(fs,l);
            phrase.push_back(l);
            //if( words.size() > 10000 ) break;
        }
    }
    fs.close();
}
```

Comment: Could you also post the line that causes the error?

Comment: Sure, I will add it in my main post.

Comment: Now I wonder if the error occurs inside the copy constructor of `SymbolGen` or when calling this copy constructor. But the latter doesn't really make sense, as the argument of the copy constructor is obviously not of type `QGroupBox*`. Can you post the content of `SymbolGen::SymbolGen(const SymbolGen &)`?

Comment: What do your `SymbolGen` constructors look like?

Comment: I added the constructor.

Comment: The constructor you posted does not take `SymbolGen&`, but `QGroupBox*`. Anyway, it seems `g` is just the parent, which should be of type `QWidget*` instead of `QGroupBox*`. You could change that in the declaration, but I'd guess there is a reason this was done this way, so the class may rely on the fact that the parent is a group box. Still, I would try to change it and see what happens.

Comment: @KarstenKoop that seemed to work! No error like the upper one appears anymore. Now my next task is to find out how I can mark your answer as accepted :D

Comment: You can't as it's only a comment, but I can post it as an answer

Comment: Sidebar: It's a thoroughly bad idea to mess with the random seed in a widget constructor, and it's likely an equally bad idea to be doing any I/O in a widget constructor.

Comment: @KubaOber I'm sorry but I'm afraid I do not get your point exactly. The constructor wasn't written by me and I am quite new to Qt and the Widget-issues. Does it mean the solution is not a good one?

Comment: It's quite simple: if you need to seed the random number generator, it probably belongs in `main()`, or some other initialization function called from main before the rest of the code starts. If you need to do I/O, don't do it in a constructor. You can easily at least defer it to the main event loop, or ideally run it concurrently in a worker thread (e.g. via `QtConcurrent::run`) so that the GUI won't block. Doing blocking I/O haphazardly during GUI startup is a major cause of bad user experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems `g` is just the parent widget, that is just passed down to the constructor of `QGroupBox`, and which should be of type QWidget* instead of QGroupBox*.

You could change that in the declaration, as the `QGroupBox` constructor expects a `QWidget*` anyway. There may be a reason this was done this way, so the class may rely on the fact that the parent is a group box. Still, I would try to change it and see what happens.